# How to get access to IntelliSense variable Data Type?

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, editor, add-on, visx

i'm trying to write a VISX extension for VS2022, which colors variables based on their Data Type, currently i'm stuck at the point where i try to get the Data type of a variable which is available to IntelliSense when hovering over a variable.
[Data type shown when hovering over Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8OFQ.png)

I already tried searching the web and asking gpt but didn't come up with an answer to this question